# Way to read CMOS 4-bit computer?

Tags: microcontroller, cmos, rom

I have a board I am trying to debug and it has a Mitsubishi 4-bit CMOS computer on it of type M34225M2-163SP:

http://pdfs.datasheetdirect.com/view/2994013/M34225M2-XXXSP.png

I assume the instructions are burned into the ROM. Is there any way to read the contents of the ROM and figure out what the computer does?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this board you're trying to debug? The copyright on the datasheet tell me that processor is at least 25 years old...

Comment: @AdamHaun Its the controller board for the sheet feeder of a HP 4si MX laser printer.

Comment: Decap it http://www.t4f.org/articles/ultra-low-cost-ic-decapsulation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug up a [full copy](http://doc.chipfind.ru/pdf/mitsubishi/m34225m1.pdf) of the datasheet (not just the first page), and I don't see a way. It's a mask ROM, so the ROM data is hard-wired in the chip during manufacturing. Unless the program itself provides a way to dump the memory, you're probably out of luck. If you can attach a logic analyzer to the pins, you can at least see what it's doing to the rest of the system.